# How to make `PlotLabels` match colour of plotted data

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

How do I make the `PlotLabels` text colour to match the one with which the data is plotted automatically, eg. in this one:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x], Cot[x]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions", Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Large, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Below], 
   Ticks -> {Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi/4], Automatic}]
```

eg. in the image below the text `cos(x)` should be in orange, `sin(x)` in blue etc.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of a simple built-in solution, but you can construct labels yourself using the default color palette.

```
exprs = {Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x], Cot[x]};
labels = MapThread[Style, {exprs, Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], Length[exprs]]}];

Plot[exprs, {x, -2 π, 2 π}, Frame -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotLabels -> Placed[labels, Below], 
 Ticks -> {Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi/4], Automatic}]
```

[image: Colored labels]